# Internet-Explorer-11 плохо работает на VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, youtube

Internet-Explorer-11 плохо работает на VirtualBox, особенно это видно когда заходишь на youtube.com. Все ужасно криво даже не видно текста в поисковой строке. Практически любое видио не воспроизводиться, хотя если зайти на youtube.com через Google Chrome то все нормально работает. На VirtualBox и реальной машине стоит одна и та же оригинальная windows 7 home premium x64, и на реальной машине таких косяков нет.

Если мне не изменяет память то когда стояла на реальной машине windows 7 home premium x32 ...то таких косяков не было

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интернет експлорер нужен для того, что бы можно было скачать нормальный браузер))))

Comment: nick_n_a ...очень умный комментарий